# Best practice to wire RS485 2 wire device to RS485 4 wire device

Tags: rs485

I am currently trying to communicate with a modbus server through a RS485/Ethernet converter. The server device is RS485 2 wire, and the converter is RS485 4 wire. As of now, I wired both Tx+ and Rx+ to the server's Data+ pin and the same for its data- pin. However, when communicating I only get echoes of the client's queries instead of proper answers from the server. According to [this forum](https://control.com/forums/threads/modbus-rs-485-4-wire-to-2-wire.17671/) the converter I use might not shut down its receivers when transmitting, thus the echoes I get.

After looking around I found two possible ways to fix the problem:

- use a converter: either buy it or make it, although I haven't found any projects about this
  online so maybe making it isn't worth it
- use something [similar to this isolator for I2C](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21798879/even-cheapskates-need-reliable-i2c-isolation), which prevent signals from coming back to their origin

Are those the only possibilities I've got? I feel like buying a converter will be the final solution but I also wanted to know about the ways to go around this problem.

Here's a sketch for more details:

[image: wiring sketch]

Comment: "The slave device is RS485 2 wire"  ... "As of now, I wired both Tx+ and Rx+ to the slave's Data+ pin" How does this make any sense? Does it have 1 differential signal or 2 differential signals? Or does it have no differential signal at all...?

Comment: you have a bad modbus master implementation.

Comment: A schematic or sketch is always helpful.  Please provide something along that line.

Comment: More importantly, the 4-wire device is not shutting down its transmitter when it should be listening for the device response. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/69898/11683

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I am using pyModbus for my master implementation, could you elaborate on how it is bad exactly ?

Comment: @DaveTweed I didn't quite get the link between your comment and the answer you linked. Is it implying that you shouldn't mix RS485 and RS422 (RS485 4 wire if i understood correctly) ?

Comment: Which type of RS485/Ethernet converter are you using. A modbus master shall send query, purge the receive buffer and start receiving, after the last character is sent. Otherwise it should discard the echo garbage. It also needs a RTS handshake to enable/disable the TX, probably the idea of using a ETH to RS485 is not the best one, you should ask the manufacturer how to use this device with Modbus. The correct device would be Modbus TCP/IP to Modbus RTU converter.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't try to mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marko Buršič implied, the problem was coming from the RS485/EtherNet converter. After looking deeper into the product I discovered it was not capable of being a Modbus gateway. I was using ICP DAS' tDS-715, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

From [EDN we have this circuit diagram](https://www.edn.com/understanding-rs-485-passive-fail-safe-biasing/). Now quite often RS485 works without pull up/down resistors, but not always

[image]

Comment: Anuja Mehendale just caught this pulllup/down problem with a 485 connected device that did not work without them. All other variants of that type of device don't need them